# How can I suppress the "copying" window during FTP upload?

Tags: vbscript, hide, copying

I want to upload a file via FTP without a "copying" dialog, and I want the script to close when finishing uploading the file (because there is sleep to upload the file, and when I remove it the code does not upload the file).

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

path = "kll.bat"
FTPUpload(path)

Sub FTPUpload(path)
  On Error Resume Next

  Const copyType = 16
  waitTime = 2000
  FTPUser  = "username"
  FTPPass  = "password"
  FTPHost  = "ftp.example.com"
  strFTP   = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost

  set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

  If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then
    set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
    strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)
    Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
    objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType
  End If

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  End If

  WScript.Sleep waitTime
End Sub
```

Comment: the line of the window of copying is (objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType) and i want to make it hide

Comment: 1.) Why is your code not indented? 2) Are you sure you want to post live usernames+passwords on the web?

Comment: 1) it is work successfully but there is problem and i want somebody to solve it 2)the user is empty mean if any body hack it there is no point with that

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): try changing `copyType` to 20 (16 + 4). If that doesn't work, then you seem to have encountered one of the situation where a flag is ignored. In that case you have to either live with the dialog, or switch to another upload method (e.g. running `ftp.exe` with an FTP script that you generate on the fly, or using [ActiveXperts' Network Component](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/ftp/vbscript/)).

Comment: can you answer the question to clarify what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), try changing `copyType` to 20 (16 + 4):

```
Sub FTPUpload(path)
  On Error Resume Next

  Const copyType = 20  'respond "Yes to All" & don't display progress dialog
  waitTime = 2000
  FTPUser  = "username"
  FTPPass  = "password"
  FTPHost  = "ftp.example.com"
  strFTP   = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost

  set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

  If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then
    set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
    strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)
    Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
    objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType
  End If

  If Err.Number  0 Then
  End If

  WScript.Sleep waitTime
End Sub
```

If that doesn't work you seem to have encountered one of the situations where a flag is ignored. In that case you have to either live with the dialog, or switch to another upload method. One option is to run `ftp.exe` with an FTP script that you generate on the fly:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

scriptfile = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetSpecialFolder(2), fso.GetTempName)
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(scriptfile, 2, True)
f.WriteLine "USER " & FTPUser
f.WriteLine "PASS " & FTPPass
...
f.WriteLine "QUIT"
f.Close

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "ftp -n -s:""" & scriptfile & """ " & FTPHost

fso.DeleteFile(scriptfile)
```

Or you could use [ActiveXperts' Network Component](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/ftp/vbscript/).